# RecyclerView does not scroll in Nested Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-nested-fragment

I am using `NavigationDrawer` and on item selection, I am changing fragment using hide/show technique instead of replace.

```
if(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_TASKS_FRAGMENT) != null){
                //if the fragment exists, show it.
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .show(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_TASKS_FRAGMENT)).commit();
            } else {
                //if the fragment does not exist, add it to fragment manager.
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.flContent,
                        BottomNavTasksFragment.newInstance(apiToken, empId), TAG_TASKS_FRAGMENT)
                        .commit();
            }
// Hide other fragments
```

The Fragmanet **BottomNavTasksFragmet** contains two fragments, one for list (RecyclerView) and other for Google Maps. However, a fragment containing RecyclerView does not respond to any touch when opened second time. It scrolls smoothly on first load but doesn't work when shown second time.

This is xml layout of **BottomNavTasksFragment**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.biocare.fragments.BottomNavTasksFragment">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:background="@color/colorSeparator"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/navigation_bar_item_bg"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_icon_color_selector"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_icon_color_selector"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_navigation" />
```

The FrameLayout `bottomNavContainer` is replaced when clicked on BottomNavigationItem.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom_nav_tasks,
            container, false);
    final BottomNavigationView navigationView = view.findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
    navigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_bottom_tasks:
                    if(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_TASKS_FRAGMENT) != null){
                        //if the fragment exists, show it.
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                                .show(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_TASKS_FRAGMENT)).commit();
                    } else {
                        //if the fragment does not exist, add it to fragment manager.
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.bottomNavContainer,
                                TasksFragment.newInstance(apiToken, empId), TAG_TASKS_FRAGMENT)
                                .commit();
                    }
                    // Hide map fragment
                    if(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_MAP_FRAGMENT) != null){
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                                .hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_MAP_FRAGMENT)).commit();
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.navigation_bottom_map:
                    if(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_MAP_FRAGMENT) != null){
                        //if the fragment exists, show it.
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                                .show(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_MAP_FRAGMENT)).commit();
                    } else {
                        //if the fragment does not exist, add it to fragment manager.
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.bottomNavContainer,
                                MapViewFragment.newInstance(apiToken, empId), TAG_MAP_FRAGMENT)
                                .commit();
                    }
                    // Hide Tasks fragment
                    if(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_TASKS_FRAGMENT) != null){
                        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                                .hide(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_TASKS_FRAGMENT)).commit();
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    FragmentTransaction t = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    TasksFragment tasksFragment = TasksFragment.newInstance(apiToken, empId);
    t.add(R.id.bottomNavContainer, tasksFragment, TAG_TASKS_FRAGMENT);
    t.commit();
    return view;
}
```

When clicked on Tasks, Scroll doesn't work. See next image]
[image: Drawer]

Stuck, RecyclerView not responding, however Menu is working
[image: List]

If further information is required, let me know.

Thanks

Comment: I am facing similar problem. Did you solve it?